# Change background color of a div in the bottom

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a following code:

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <section>
      <div class="flex flex-col flex-auto w-full min-w-0">
        <div class="m-2">
          <div
            class="bg-gray-100 p-6 rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow border-b border-gray-300 text-gray-900">
            <div><h1 class="text-2xl font-bold mb-2 text-gray-800">Run</h1>
              <h2>Run variables</h2>
              <ul>
                <li><input class="m-1" placeholder="Name" value="">
                  <input class="m-1" placeholder="Value" value="">
                </li>
                <li><input class="m-1" placeholder="Name" value="">
                  <input class="m-1" placeholder="Value" value="">
                </li>
                <li><input class="m-1" placeholder="Name" value="">
                  <input class="m-1" placeholder="Value" value="">
                </li>
                <li><input class="m-1" placeholder="Name" value="">
                  <input class="m-1" placeholder="Value" value="">
                </li>
              </ul>
              </p>
              <div class="bg-gray-300">
                <button class="m-1">Go</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the grey div on the bottom to ignore margin and padding of the outer div, so it looks like the outer div is darker in the bottom. How do I do that using Tailwind?

Here's a link to the tailwind playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/myBWPsTLJT

Comment: Just move it out of that div https://play.tailwindcss.com/mReIdD4o4f

Comment: @php_nub_qq but then the rounded corners on the bottom are wrong

Comment: You can add the rounded classes as desired.. Much better solution rather than the accepted answer.

Comment: @php_nub_qq why is it better? I'd have to use a negative margin anyway to hide the bottom rounded corners of the top container.

Comment: Because what happens if in the next version of tailwind m-2 gets changed from 2px to 3px? It's simple when you have 1 change like this, but if it becomes your standard practice very soon you'll find yourself with dozens of those and updating will become impossible at one point. The solution I've provided makes sure your code is inline with the framework's standards and you can easily use `rounded-t-lg` to avoid having radius on the bottom of your upper div.

Comment: [Here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/dgTlB3tTM1) is an updated example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play with negative margins!

[..and that should be your result!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQNfp.png)

```
.bg-gray-300 {
    width: 106%;
    margin: 40px -24px -24px -24px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 24px;
}
```